# Restricting VBA code to certain range of cells within worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am currently running code that changes cell colour and value when clicked i.e. one click changes cell colour and sets value to 1, double click same cell to remove colour and number. This is to allow people to fill in a form in a visual way, and gives me the ability to count the "checked" cells.  My problem is that I need it restricted to a certain range within that worksheet so that people can't overwrite other cells.

I have next to no coding experience, and the code below is a mix and match of a bunch of stuff found online.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Worksheet_SelectionChange Target   
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Range("E4:K79") Is Nothing Or .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Select Case .Value
        Case ""
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 40
        Case 1
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            .Value = vbNullString
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
        End Select
    .Value = .Value + 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Worksheet_SelectionChange Target

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If Intersect(.Cells, Range("E4:K120")) Is Nothing Or .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        Select Case .Value
        Case ""
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Case 1
            .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
            .Value = vbNullString
        Exit Sub
        Case Else
        Exit Sub
        End Select
            .Value = .Value + 1
    End With

End Sub
```